# Filter out a DataTable by avoid some of its distinct columns

Tags: c#, sql-server, filter, datatable

I have a DataTable named **dtEmployee** with four columns, viz. EmployeeId, EmployeePosition, SupervisorPosition, SupervisorId which all are of type varchar(10).

[image]

***I want to filter the results in dtEmployee whose result is equivalent to SQL Query below.***

```
Select * from dtEmployee where EmployeePosition not in (Select distinct SupervisorPosition
from dtEmployee);
```

I have achieved the sub query equivalent by creating another DataTable named **dtDistinctSupervisors** as

```
dtDistinctSupervisors = dtEmployee.DefaultView.ToTable(true, "SupervisorPosNum");
```

This is equivalent to `Select distinct SupervisorPosition
    from dtEmployee`

How can I get the whole query equivalent.

Your help is appreciated. Thanks.

- Merin

Answer (score 1):

Having `Distinct` inside an `IN` subquery makes no difference. This should dot it:

```
var dt = dtEmployee.AsEnumerable();
var result = dt.Where(emp => !dt.Any(sup => 
                               sup.Field<string>("SupervisorPosition") == 
                               emp.Field<string>("EmployeePosition")));
```

And to show the result in the Console:

```
foreach (DataRow row in result) // Loop over the rows.
{
    Console.WriteLine("--- Row ---");
    foreach (var item in row.ItemArray)
    {
      Console.Write("Item: ");
      Console.WriteLine(item);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your input Magnus. Could you also please help me to populate the data inside **result** and calculate the count of items inside **result**.

Comment: What do you mean by "populate"? You can append a `.ToList()` as the end to get a list for rows.

Comment: Populate means to see all the row items inside **result**.

Comment: @MerinNakarmi You would need some kind of visual component and that depends on which environment you are working in.

Comment: I am using Visual Studio 20012. I just want to print them in command prompt using Console.WriteLine();

Comment: I want to iterate through the items inside the **result**. Is it possible to convert **result** to DataTable? If so, how?

Comment: Thank you very much for your precious time **Magnus**. The datatypes of all columns in the DataTable being varchar(10), I had to slightly modify the query. 
i.e. use `Field<string>` instead of `Field<int>`.

Comment: But it did not filter any rows. :( :(

Comment: @MerinNakarmi Make sure there are not unwanted empty spaces in the end of the strings being compared

Comment: There aren't any empty space.. :(